# Returning on an old project without repositories

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

Some days ago I tried to return to an old project I was working on with a friend, but a problem came up and I cant figure out what to do right now.

To be more specific, we (my friend and me) live in different world places, and my friend was the one owning the `SVN` hosting, but its been three years the `SVN` repositories went down and so I can't download them with eclipse, anyway, I actually own the whole project in a disc, which is the same that was on the `SVN`, and I want to put it on eclipse to start working again, so, the question is, what have I to do to set on the project if I have not the repositories to download it and make it work on eclipse?

> Additonal info:
>
> -Last used JRE version: 7.09
>
> -Last used Eclipse version: 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse: File->Import->Existing project into Workspace and follow wizard...